# Django aggregation Many To Many into list of dict

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, aggregation

It's been hours since I tried to perform this operation but I couldn't figure it out.

Let's say I have a Django project with two classes like these:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField()
   address=models.ManyToManyField(to=Address)

class Address(models.Model):
   city=models.CharField()
   zip=models.IntegerField()
```

So it's just a simple Person having multiple addresses.
Then I create some objects:

```
addr1=Address.objects.create(city='first', zip=12345)
addr2=Address.objects.create(city='second', zip=34555)
addr3=Address.objects.create(city='third', zip=5435)
person1=Person.objects.create(name='person_one')
person1.address.set([addr1,addr2])
person2=Person.objects.create(name='person_two')
person2.address.set([addr1,addr2,addr3])
```

Now it comes the hard part, I want to make a single query that will return something like that:

```
result = [
    {
      'name': 'person_one',
      'addresses': [
          {
            'city':'first',
            'zip': 12345
          },
          {
              'city': 'second',
              'zip': 34555
          }
      ]  
    },
    {
        'name': 'person_two',
        'addresses': [
            {
                'city':'first',
                'zip': 12345
            },
            {
                'city': 'second',
                'zip': 34555
            },
            {
                'city': 'third',
                'zip': 5435
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The best i could get was using ArrayAgg and JSONBAgg operators for Django (I'm on POSTGRESQL BY THE WAY):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import JSONBAgg, ArrayAgg
result = Person.objects.values(
   'name',
   addresses=JSONBAgg('city')
)
```

But that's not enough, I can't pull a lit of dictionaries out of the query directly as I would like to do, just a list of values or something useless using:

```
addresses=JSONBAgg(('city','zip'))
```

which returns a dictionari with random keys and the strings I passed as input as values.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I think DRF serializers might help you with this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/. Also, from what I see, not sure why do you have M2M for Person -> Address relation, shouldn't that be one to many?

Answer (score 3):

If you use postgres, you can do this:

```py
subquery = Address.objects.filter(person_id=OuterRef("pk")).annotate(
    data=JSONObject(city=F("city"), zip=F("zip"))
).values_list("data")

persons = Persons.objects.annotate(addresses=ArraySubquery(subquery))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement: To make an aggregation of customized JSON objects after group_by (values) in Django.

Currently, to my knowledge, Django is not providing any function to aggregate manually created JSON objects. There are a couple of ways to solve this. Firstly, make a customized function which is quite laborious. However, there is another approach that is pretty much easy, using both aggregate functions (ArrayAgg or JSONBAgg) and RawSQL together.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import JSONBAgg, ArrayAgg
result = Person.objects.values('name').annotate(addresses=JSONBAgg(RawSQL("json_build_object('city', city, 'zip', zip)", ())))
```

I hope it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can try, if the fields you need from the ManyToManyField are not much, is to chain the annotation and create a dictionary from it.

E.g

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import JSONBAgg
result = Person.objects.values(
   'name',
   addresses_cities=JSONBAgg('address__city')
   addresses_zips=JSONBAgg('address__zip')
)
```

then you can loop through the result queryset and create a dictionary from the address_cities and addresses_zips array like below:

```
address_dict=[
{"city": city, "zip": zip_} for city, zip_ in zip(result["addresses_cities"],result["addresses_zips"])
]
```

This works for me. I hope it helps.

Edit: 6/24/2023

Found a better way and thought to update this response.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import JSONBAgg
from django.db.models import (
CharField,
Func,
SlugField,
Value,
)
 result = Person.objects.values(
   ...
  tags=ArrayAgg(
                Func(
                    Value("name"),#the name of the json key
                    "tags__name",
                    Value("slug"),
                    "tags__slug", #referencing the slug field from the Tags M2M Model
                    function="jsonb_build_object",
                    output_field=CharField, #this can be any field type. It's important to unify all fields especially if you are filtering for different field types. E.g above I was filtering for tags__slug (SlugField) and tags__name (CharField). Django threw an error that I have to specify a field type. Doing so fixed the error.
                ),
                distinct=True, #to prevent duplicates
            )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`person.address` already holds a queryset of addresses. From there you can use list-comprehension / model_from_dict to get the values you want.